# Typescript set the schema of a module file

Tags: typescript, module, intellisense

Basically, when I dynamically import a file, I want it to match some specifications. I want my file to have some way of showing that, so that intellisense understands what my file needs to be shaped like (essentially a schema for a typescript module).

```
//My module

import * as fetch from 'node-fetch';
import { Cache } from '../cache'; //Because this path is relative, the path of this script must be immediately under the root of the project
let jq = "";
let error = "";
let url = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.2.1/dist/jquery.js";
export function desc(){
    return "Adds jquery to the hackscripts list.";
}
export function name(){ return "jqhack" }
export function id(){ return "sys.modsExtra.jqhack" }
export async function preload(cache: Cache){
    let err = false;
    jq = await cache.load_cached("jqhack.jq", ()=>fetch(url).then(res => res.text(), err => {
        err = true;
        return `[ERROR] ${err}`;
    }));
    if(err) {
        error = `Failed to fetch "${url}".)`;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
export function getErr(){
    return error;
}
export function impl(sys){
    sys.hackscripts.register("Jquery 3.2.1", jq);
}
```

```
interface Module{
    name():string;
    id():string;
    
    preload(cache: Cache):Promise<void>;
    impl(sys:SystemStatus, cache: Cache):ModuleStatus;

    getErr?():string;
}
```

My goal isn't that the module loader on my side of the code understands what type it is, my goal is that the modules themselves know what they need to export.